# Does Russia Prevent Gold Exports?

Tags: international-trade

[The Sirius Report tweets](https://twitter.com/thesiriusreport/status/976166420596908032):

> Surprises me how anyone imagines that #Russia only has 1800+ tons. **Just look at the fact that they never export #gold production** and what they have annually produce for years. That is just for starters,

Soviet Union aside, from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_gold_production), we see that gold production in Russia (graph) seems to have stayed above 100 metric tons a year (minimum of 100 x 20 years would be 2000).  I can't find any support for "Russia doesn't allow gold exports" or that they've ever done this, though it's possible they did this during the Soviet Era.  I can find Russian gold coins (latest year) on GovMint, so it seems like they are allowing non-Russians to buy gold, or is this gold from other countries?

Is there any evidence that Russia does not allow gold exports and circumstances which may warrant exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such evidence, because Russia does export gold, though it also adds to its reserves

For example Sputnik News (established by the Russian government-controlled news agency Rossiya Segodnya) [reported](https://sputniknews.com/russia/201803061062261032-gold-exports-russia/)

> Exports of fine gold from Russia increased 2,5 times to 56,6 tons (1,82 million oz) last year, compared to 22,4 tons in 2016, according to the Russian State Assaying Chamber under the Ministry of Finance.
>
> ...
>
> Russia's precious metals refineries reportedly produced 306,9 tons (9,867 million oz) of gold in 2017, which is 6,4 percent more than 288,6 tons produced in 2016. 18,4 percent of all the gold produced in the country was exported, while the rest 224 tons of the metal were purchased by the Central Bank of Russia to add to the country's gold and foreign currency reserves, RIA Novosti reported.
>
> ...
>
> "The exports (of gold) in 2017 were not as high as they were in 2014 — 140 tons", the expert told RIA Novosti.